# Unique Record Filter

Tags: vba, excel, unique

I wrote code to perform unique record filter for the worksheet columns, and copy each column (after the filter) into a new worksheet. Current code looks like this:

```
sub Test()
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(3)).Name = "Unique Filter"

For i = 1 To 12
    Sheets("Sheet3").Columns(i).Copy Sheets("Unique Filter").Columns(i)
Next

Worksheets("Unique Filter").Activate

For i = 1 To 12
    Columns(i).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
Next

End sub
```

It creates a new worksheet after the current one (that's the worksheet number 3 in my workbook).

The macro leaves me the new Excel "Unique Filter" as follow, which doesn't look right: (there should be around 600 unique records in the original 10K lines from the sheet 3, instead of 1)

[image: After macro runs (there should be more than one line as there are other unique records!]

Comment: Step through the code and see what is going on.Press F8 to step through the code.[Step through code example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ijw_jp9fhTI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to skip the initial copy-paste and instead use the copy-paste feature of the Advanced Filter.  I always get unexpected results if I don't  - hidden rows and such.  Probably all explainable, but I never looked into it and found this to be a quicker solution.

So - modifying your code a bit...

```
sub Test()
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(3)).Name = "Unique Filter"

For i = 1 to 12
Sheets("Sheet3").Columns(i).AdvancedFilter _
    xlFilterCopy, , Sheets("Unique Filter").Columns(i), True
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Rovsom. I noticed you missed the next, for the For loop. Other than that, looks good. Thanks

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry about that, bit sloppy of me.  Will fix it up.  Cheers.

Comment: Do you know how would it work to add a worksheet after the one I am currently on?

Comment: Hey Francisco - you can just use the "ActiveSheet" object reference, instead of e.g. "Worksheets(3)".  So the first line becomes:   `Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet).Name = "Unique Filter"`